# How to replace bindActionCreators and to use mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

We are calling an API using bindActionCreators and every time I need to use `this.props` to post and to get data.

The problem is that I need to store the response data in some variable and access it through `this.props.variable`. For example:

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(connect(  
    state => state.sensi,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(FetchSensi));
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mapStateToProps**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  variableName: state.someVariableFromState
});
```

and i don't use mapDispatchToProps, i pass directly action to connect like this

```
import {action1, action2} from './someActionFolder';

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {action1, action2})(YourComponent);
```

and inside your component you can use your actions like

```
this.props.action1();
this.props.action2();
```

you can also combine all your actions like

```
import * as actions from './yourActionsFolder';
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions);
```

Comment: variableName refers to?

Comment: that is how you set your variable name, because you return an object with key-value pairs, key is your variable name as u like it, and value whould be value from state that you want. That name is how you access it from props. this.props.variableName